# Update counter for GUI, for every high signal from GPIO

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to input a signal from GPIO and I've assigned it to a counter where it will count every high signal input. However, GUI only shows '1'. I am probably confused with the loop, as the counter won't increment.

I understand that the GUI is blocking, but I don't know how to implement it.

Here is the following attempt that I have tried:

```py
from guizero import App, Text
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

sensor = 16

global count

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(sensor,GPIO.IN)

app = App("Counter")
text = Text(app, text="1")

#when GPIO is high, however this only stops to 1
if GPIO.input(sensor):
    print('detected')
    def counter():
        #add counter and change value by adding one
        text.value = int(text.value) + 1
    while GPIO.input(sensor):
        time.sleep(0.01)
           
app.display()
```

Comment: most GUI have some function to run code with delay (`tkinter` has `after(milliseconds, function_name)`, `PyQT` has `QTimer`)  and it can be used to run some code periodically without blocing main loop in GUI.

Comment: you never run `counter()` so it never update it. You only defined function but you have to execute it inside `while`-loop (or with something similar)

Comment: You can't change the contents of a `Text` widget by setting a `text` attribute, you have to use methods such as `.insert()` and `.delete()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is you defined function `counter()` but you didn't execute it inside `while`-loop.

But there is different problem - most GUIs don't like loop because it blocks mainloop used by GUI to get (key/mouse/etc.) events for system, send them to widgets, update widget. But most GUIs have some method to execute function with delay and it can be used to execute code periodically without using loop.

I can't test it but it could be

```
from guizero import App, Text
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# --- functions ---

def counter():
    if GPIO.input(sensor):
        text.value = int(text.value) + 1
    else:
        text.cancel(counter) # stop this loop
        #app.destroy() # exit program   

# --- main ---

sensor = 16

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN)

app = App("Counter")
text = Text(app, text="1")

text.repeat(10, counter)  # Schedule call to counter() every 10ms (0.01s)

app.display()
```

---

**BTW:** using Google I found solution in `guizero` doc: [Loops and sleeping](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/blocking/) and [App](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/app/) (see `Methods` in `App`).

Comment: Thank you, i see what you're doing, but it seems the text.repeat(10, counter) only repeats the count for every 10ms to infinity without stopping as i have run it. However, when i add if GPIO.input(sensor) == 0, the count only works when the logic input is high, but it's not incremental by 1.

Comment: I can't test code because I don't have RPI but I found you can use `text.cancel(couter)` to stop loop. See changes in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may call counter() function for counter implementation in while loop here as:
**counter()** before time.sleep(0..01)
I guess it helps.